# Trigonometric functional equation $g(x)f(y) = f \left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2-f\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $ f,g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ that satisfy the functional equation
> $$g(x)f(y) = f \left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2-f\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2$$
> for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

I need hints for this problem.

Comment: Doesn't this force $$\frac{f \left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2-f\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2}{f(x)}$$ to be a constant function of $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some hints/remarks about necessity**: Play around with the substitutions $y = x$, $y = -x$ to show that necessarily either

Case 1: $f$ must be an odd function, or

Case 2: $g \equiv 0$.

If in Case 1, go on to show either

Case 1(a): $g \equiv f$, or

Case 1(b): $f \equiv 0$. In this case $g$ can be any arbitrary function.

If in Case 2, show that necessarily $f = c$ for some constant $c$.

The remaining bit which I haven't any suggestions is Case 1(a). In this case, it is *sufficient* if $f$ is a linear function: $f(ax + y) = af(x) + f(y)$ for $a,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, but I don't know if it is *necessary*.

Comment: For more about Case 1(a), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/633461/229831). Note that substituting $x+y$ for $x$ and $x-y$ for $y$ in $f(x)f(y)=f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2-f\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)^2$, one gets $f(x+y)f(x-y)=f(x)^2-f(y)^2$.